# Laravel notification and mail component error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laragon

What could be the reason for these errors in the local dev server? I tried lots of different ways markdown, notification. Then I published and attempted to remove @components from Blade files, and then views worked. I am using Laragon with Laravel 8 and PHP 7.3/8.

> exception: "Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException" file:
> "C:\laragon\www...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail/resources/views/html/button.blade.php"
> line: 10 message: "Undefined variable $url (View:
> C:\laragon\www...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\resources\views\html\button.blade.php)"
> exception: "Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException" file:
> "C:\laragon\www...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail/resources/views/html/header.blade.php"
> line: 3 message: "Undefined variable $url (View:
> C:\laragon\www...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\resources\views\html\header.blade.php)

Comment: I do not understand, it works or no?

Comment: No, without components yes, but I need them to work.

Comment: pls write some code

Comment: I don't think this is code related. As I followed documentation. Even defaults that are provided out of the box are not working on local server. So it might be related to configuration because it works on my production server.